# printing all the binary posible with 3 length

Tags: python-3.x

while running this code its showing

> digit(digit - 1, pref + str(0))
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'int

```
def digit(n, pref):
    if digit == 0:
        print(pref)
    else:
        digit(digit - 1, pref + str(0))

        digit(digit - 1, pref + str(1))


print(digit(3, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're treating `digit` as if it was `n` in some places in your code, replace it with `n` and it'll work:

```
def digit(n, pref):
    if n == 0:
        print(pref)
    else:
        digit(n - 1, pref + '0') # just use '0', '1' instead of str(...)
        digit(n - 1, pref + '1')


digit(3, '')
```

Output:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Note that use can also use `itertools.product` for this task:

```
from itertools import product
print([''.join(p) for p in product('01', repeat=3)])
```

Output:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Comment: oops that such a noobish mistake. I am just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

this would be a simpler way:

```
def digit(n):
    for i in range(1<<n):
        print(f'{i:0{n}b}')

digit(3)
```

`1<<n` is just `2` to the power of `n` and then i print the number in binary with n binary places (filled by zero if necessary).

this could be shortened to

```
n=3
print('\n'.join(f'{i:0{n}b}' for i in range(1<<n)))
```

which would then generate your output.